# Match repeated pattern in a query string using a regex

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a series of URL params and I need extract some of them that are repeated. For example:

**Required params "m"**

I have a string how this:

```
m=123456789&reset=true&color=blue&getppm=1112&comparechars=yes&alternatem=5&.....
```

This repeats about 10 times with different values.

I have this regex:

```
m=(.*?)&
```

But my problem is that other params are entering too (`getppm`, `alternatem`).

`m` is the first in some cases. It could vary in some cases, and I can't use `&m=` in such cases.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
The m param normally is continued by a serie of numbers and uppercase letters on this type:

```
m=1A2B3C4D6D8A7D5S.32D4D1D5D3D6D8D&nextparam=...
```

I was trying with {x,x} variations without successfull

Comment: Isn't `m` always preceded by some specific character? Define "vary in some cases"!

Comment: Difficult to understand logic of repeating pattern here.

Comment: Sometimes m is preceded by &, others by ", others by blank space, others by comma,.... its difficult because this varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this is using the "word boundary" regex `\b`.

To extract the value of the "m" parameter:

```
String m = str.replaceAll(".*?\\bm=([^&]+).*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

GET parameter key-value pairs are delimited by `&` (prepended by `?` for the first key-value pair in the URL).

You could simply use a lookbehind to limit the parameter to actual `m` instead of `[something]m`.

For instance:

```
String params = "myUrl?m=123456789&reset=true&color=blue&getppm=1112&comparechars=yes&alternatem=5&...";
// Pattern improved as per Pschemo's suggestion
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=&|\\?)m=([^&?]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(params);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
123456789
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `.+?` consider using `[^&?]+`. This way you wouldn't need to check `(.+?)(?=&|\\?)` conditions - which probably should also contain end of string `$` if `m=...` would be last parameter).